# Placing header files in a subdirectory of /usr/include with automake?

Tags: header-files, autotools, automake

If I write a library, and have header files for development included, and have a `src/Makefile.am` like this:

```
AM_CFLAGS = -std=c99 -Wall -Werror -Os
lib_LTLIBRARIES = libmylibrary.la
libmylibrary_la_SOURCES = a.c b.c
include_HEADERS = a.h b.h
```

Everything works nicely. However, `a.h` and `b.h` are installed directly under `/usr/include` (or `/usr/local/include`). What should I do to get them installed, in a subdirectory specific to my library, e.g. `/usr/include/mylibrary`?

Answer (score 26, accepted):

As well as `pkginclude_HEADERS`, which you mention, you can also install header files into an arbitrary subdirectory of `/usr/include` with any name you like, like this:

```
otherincludedir = $(includedir)/arbitrary_name
otherinclude_HEADERS = a.h b.h
```

The advantage of using pkginclude_HEADERS = publicHeader.h is that in a large system, each package stay in its own subdirectory of $prefix/include and avoids the chance of overwriting headers from different package with the same name.  Furthermore, this naming convention helps users easily locate the header for a particular package.

Comment: I keep getting Makefile.am:9: error: 'otherinclude_HEADERS' is used but 'otherincludedir' is undefined

(figured it out, I needed to use a name specified as a subdir, in this case 'include' instead of 'otherinclude')

Comment: (nope that didn't work, it keeps going to include/PropID.h instead of includes/7zip/PropID.h)

Comment: (derp, I'm dyslexic, otherinclude*dir* not just otherinclude)

Answer (score 9):

Looks like I asked Stack Overflow too quickly ;)
With a little more searching, I found that if I use `pkginclude_HEADERS` instead of `include_HEADERS`, the headers go in `/usr/include/[package name]`.

http://realmike.org/blog/2010/07/18/gnu-automake-by-example/

Comment: Have you ever managed to avoid placing header into `[package name]`subdir? I mean: could be all headers installed directly into `/usr/include/`?

Comment: @LPs Did not quite understand what you are asking about. As Delan said earlier, he used `include_HEADERS` and files were installed directly under `/usr/include`