# How do I use pkginclude_HEADERS and Automake to get a second include directory?

Tags: automake

Much of this topic was covered in this thread on [pkginclude_HEADERS](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603902/placing-header-files-in-a-subdirectory-of-usr-include-with-automake)

I have an open source library and it has some includes with common names. I suspect the best solution is to have my umbrella include file in the pkginclude_HEADERS directory, then have an additional directory there that has all the other headers in it. Then in the umbrella file the usage will be #include .

How can I coerce automake to do this? Thanks!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Most likely:

```
nobase_pkginclude_HEADERS = subdir/subfile.h
```

so `subfile.h` gets copied to `${pkgincludedir}/subdir/subfile.h`. Without the `nobase_` prefix, it would end up as `${pkgincludedir}/subfile.h`.

Comment: So, this will work for all but the "umbrella" header file - the one that references all the others. Can I define a pkginclude_HEADERS macro too (without the no base) for that one umbrella file?

Comment: (It's not a macro, it is a variable), and yes, `pkginclude_HEADERS = umbrella.h`.