# How to have automake install headers file in a subdirectory of include

Tags: makefile, autotools, autoconf, libtool

My current project has a couple files in its `include/tatoparser` directory that I would like to distribute along with my library.

```
qdii@nomada ~/MyProject $ ls include/tatoparser/
dataset.h  interface_lib.h  linkset.h  sentence.h  tagset.h
```

I created a `Makefile.am` that references those files:

```
qdii@nomada ~/MyProject $ cat include/Makefile.am 
include_HEADERS = tatoparser/interface_lib.h tatoparser/sentence.h tatoparser/dataset.h tatoparser/tagset.h tatoparser/linkset.h
```

But when I run `make install` the referenced files get copied into `/usr/include` (or whatever `$(includedir)` was set to), and I want them copied in `/usr/include/tatoparser`.

How can I do that?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [placing header files in a subdirectory of /usr/include with automake?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5603902/placing-header-files-in-a-subdirectory-of-usr-include-with-automake)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the `nobase` prefix to stop Automake from stripping the subdirectory path from the files:

```
nobase_include_HEADERS = tatoparser/interface_lib.h tatoparser/...
```